# Is there a function in sql server "isEmpty" return data if the select return empty result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
EmpId  No_of_days
  1       24
  2       28
  6       24
  7       30
  8       10
  9       15
```

when I write a select statement

```
SELECT No_of_days FROM _table WHERE EmpId = 3 or 4 or 5
```

I got an empty result set.

I want the result set return 0 days for employees 3 and 4 and 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Assuming*** that you have another table with all your employees in (if not, where are employees 3, 4 and 5 coming from?), you could use a `LEFT JOIN` onto your example table (`_table`):

```
SELECT e.empid,
       ISNULL(t.No_of_days,0)
FROM Employee e --No idea what your employee table is actually called, so guessed.
     LEFT JOIN _table t ON e.empid = t.empid;
```

This will provide rows for all your employees. If you wanted just 3, 4 and 5, then you would add your `WHERE`:

```
 WHERE e.empid IN (3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `values()` construct & do `left join` :

```
select tt.empid, isnull(t.No_of_days, 0)
from ( values (3), (4), (5) 
     ) tt (empid) left join
     table t
     on t.empid = tt.empid;
```

**EDIT :** If you have a more `employee`s id then you have to maintain one staging table & do `left join` :

```
select tt.empid,
       ISNULL(t.No_of_days, 0)
from table tt left join -- possible employee id table
     [_table] t
     on t.empid = tt.empid;
```

Comment: this means that i know the empty ids first ? how will this work for thousands of records ? 3 and 4 and 5 are only an example not esist in real world

Answer (score 1):

use `coalesce`

```
   select coalesce(No_of_days,0) 
  from _table WHERE EmpId in( 3 , 4 , 5)
```

BTW use `In` instead `or` and if you have to push those id in `EmpId` 1st then 
coalesce() will work otherwise if no values in empid then it will not work

Comment: How will this work? If there are no rows for `EmpID` 3, 4 or 5 the dataset will still return no rows. The OP isn't looking for a total aggregate, but an aggregate at each `empID`.

Comment: this means that i know the empty ids first ? how will this work for thousands of records ? 3 and 4 and 5 are only an example not esist in real world